# Passing 2d Vector by Reference, Changes Not Persisting

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

So in my program, I'm using polymorphism, which could also explain some of the issues that I'm having.
This is my pure abstract class:

```
class Event {
 public:
     Event();
     ~Event();
     virtual int returnType();
```

};

Then I have a room class that sets events to a particular room:

```
 class Room {
 private:
     Event * e;
     bool player = false;
     bool bEvent = false;
 public:
     Room();
     ~Room();
     Event * getEvent();
     void setEvent(Event *);
     bool getPlayer();
     void setPlayer(bool);
     bool getBoolEvent();
     void setBoolEvent(bool);
 };
```

And here are my function definitions:

```
 Event * Room::getEvent() {
     return e;
 }
 
 void Room::setEvent(Event * n) {
     e = n;
 }
 bool Room::getPlayer() {
     return player;
 }
 
 void Room::setPlayer(bool p) {
     player = p;
 }
 
 bool Room::getBoolEvent() {
     return bEvent;
 }
 
 void Room::setBoolEvent(bool b) {
     bEvent = b;
 }
```

Here is my bats class which is a derived class from event: The functions are the same, so here are the function definitions:

```
 int Bats::returnType() {
     return 1;
 }
```

So in my program, I am using a 2d vector of Rooms, and then assigning events to these rooms via polymorphism. The problem is that I don't think the changes are persisting, at least with the polymorphism, even when passing by reference.
Here is the function where I am setting the bat event to a certain room in the 2d vector:

```
vector<vector<Room>> Game::setEvents(vector<vector<Room>> &grid) {
    Bats b1;
    Event * eb1 = &b1;
    //Set player
    int r1 = rand()%gridSize;
    int r2 = rand()%gridSize;
    grid[r1][r2].setPlayer(true);
    //Set bats
    grid[0][0].setBoolEvent(true);
    grid[0][0].setEvent(eb1);
    cout << "Function example: " << grid[0][0].getEvent()->returnType() << endl;
    return grid;
}
```

As an output I get `Function example: 1`;

However, when we move into the main (in this case Game::play()) function, these changes don't hold.

```
void Game::play() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    //Create vector
    vector<vector<Room>> grid;
    //Fill vector
    fillGrid(grid);
    //Set player and events
    grid = setEvents(grid);
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j].getBoolEvent() == true) {
                cout << i << " " << j << endl;
                cout << grid[i][j].getEvent()->returnType() << endl;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

As an output I get `0 0` and then a seg fault.
Although the boolEvent is still true, for some reason I get a segmentation fault when trying to call returnType(), even though it worked in the setEvents() function. What am I doing wrong with polymorphism?

Comment: Please combine these snippets into a [mre] so we can copy and compile it _as-is_.

Comment: You are giving the `Room` a pointer to a local variable. Then `setEvents` returns, its local variables are destroyed, and the `Room` ends up holding a dangling pointer. Any attempt to use that pointer exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: So how do I make sure that it doesn't destroy that variable? Define the variable in the main?